# How to write sphinx queries with OR condition

Tags: sphinx

I need to create a sphinx query in my project with OR condition. But giving an OR condition like

```
select cost FROM transactionsChart WHERE cost=25 OR cost=5;
```

is not working. It returns an error like

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected OR, expecting $end near 'OR cost=5'
```

Can anybody help me....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

Sphinx doesnt support `OR` in the WHERE clause, **only** `AND`.

For your specific example, could use `IN` syntax,

```
sphinxql> SELECT cost FROM transactionsChart WHERE cost IN (5,25);
```

or a more general solution is to use a virtual attribute

```
sphinxql> SELECT cost, IF(cost=25 OR cost=5,1,0) AS filter 
      FROM transactionsChart WHERE filter = 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with

```
select cost FROM transactionsChart WHERE cost=25 | cost=5;
```

[Source - Official Documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/extended-syntax.html)

Comment: **Nope that won't work**. The documentation you link to is for extended syntax, which is the full text syntax understood inside the `MATCH(...)` clause, it DOESN'T apply for the rest of the WHERE clause.