# Using 'OR' in SphinxQL

Tags: sphinx

I can use pipes in side the `MATCH` in SphinxQl e.g.

`Select * from idx_A where MATCH('(@(Title) Apple)|(@(Body) Orange)')`

but not outside the match

`Select * from idx_A where MATCH('(@(Title) Apple)|(@(Body) Orange)') and Title='Apple' or Body='Orange'`

as I get an error similar to:

```
[Err] 1064 - sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected OR, expecting $end near 'or Body='Orange`
```

Am I using incorrect syntax outside of the MATCH() or is it not possible to construct here using 'OR'?

Comment: No, can't use OR in the 'WHERE'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199579/how-to-write-sphinx-queries-with-or-condition and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333103/where-clause-has-or-in-sphinx for some suggestions

Comment: @barryhunter @BarryHunter Thanks the IN I've used already for this but it only applies to  single field e.g. `userID in (1,2,3)`.  In my case I am trying to mix two different fields e.g. `userid in (1,2,3) OR productid in (1,2,3)`.  I tried initially doing those inside match eg. `(@(userid) 1|2|3)|(@(productid) 1|2|3)` which naturally does work yet the whole reason I moved to the `in` outside of `Match` is I had a large set of values for both fields and MATCH was both a) slower and b) failed so I was forced to move large OR pipes outside of it. I will give your `Virtual Attribute` some thought